# Reverse a teleport command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I cancel a teleport command in Minecraft on Xbox one? My son put in a `TP 708,112,40` command and didn't save. And now he is not being able to get to a location of his game.

Comment: It sounds like what you are asking is how do you *reverse* a TP command.  As far as I am aware, once a command executes, you cannot cancel its action.  The only way your son will get back to where is started is if you TP back to the coordinates, or if he can manage to find where he was by walking around.

Answer (score 2):

If he hasn’t changed his spawn point by sleeping in a bed (or using `/spawnpoint`) you should be able to kill yourself and it will put you at your last spawnpoint.

How to kill yourself in Minecraft:

1. Jump into the void.
2. Go into survival mode and burn yourself in lava.